# My PC is deleting all of my files

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, memory, lenovo-desktop-computer

I got a new PC in the last December (Lenovo All-In-One C260).
It was normal the first month, but now, when I switch it on it took a long time to turn on and all my files were deleted. Also, when I open any of my applications, it is as if it is the first time I'm using them, even the background gets changed back to the default. However, the files that I have deleted before (in the Recycle Bin) are there. Ever since the first time time this happened, every time I turn on my computer it happens again.

Originally, I thought that the problem was with my RAM. I checked the usage and found that it was at 3.9/4GB. Should I change my RAM or add another stick? Or is the RAM not the problem?

Please help me as I lost a lot of my projects and files and wish to recover them.

Comment: Well first of all your ram has 0 to do with files being deleted so no don't replace your memory. Secondly, check the administrator settings. IT sounds like there may be a policy being implemented that keeps the same original settings always.

Comment: i should be I. You don't need capital letters part way through a paragraph as you have done...

Comment: It sounds like your user profile folder is messed up. Go to `C:\Users` and open the user profile folders you find there and see if any of them contain your files.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though there was a problem with your original profile and Microsoft created a temporary new one for you. The Recycle Bin shows up because those files do not exist within the User Profile directories.

Open a File Explorer window and look at C:\Users.

Inside there you'll probably find a few folders, including one with your UserName, and one with your UserName.ComputerName or something similar. The one named just your UserName is your original profile, the other one is your temporary profile.

This happens when there is an error in your user settings, and to recover, Windows has to use the default settings for a new user.

As Eric F mentioned, this is not an issue with your RAM.

There are ways to repair this, but in my experience the best thing to do is to create a new profile, move your files over, and delete your old one.

So, first open the **Control Panel**, and go to **User Accounts**.

Under **Manage User Accounts** you'll need to create a new user account.

Now, sign out of your current account and sign in using the *new account* you just created. This will create the new profile folders you'll need to put your old files into.

Now, open **File Explorer** again, and go back to C:\Users\YourOldUserName.

You may not have access to this folder at first. If the computer asks if you want access to it, tell it "yes".

If it just tells you that you do not have access, **right-click** on the folder and select **Properties**. Open the **Security** tab and click **Advanced**. At the top of this window is an **Owner** field: click **Change**. Enter the username of your new account and press OK.

Now you should be able to open the folder and copy the files to your new profile directory.